# What to call after validateUser() for forms authentication?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I made a custom membership provider and overrode the ValidateUser method, but now I am confused. I am not using any Login controls, I just have a site wide login (username and password box) on a masterpage.

**Questions:**

1. Do I need to call the ValidateUser() method myself? If so, what are
   the next steps to take? Do I create the auth cookie which methods do I need to call to complete the login?
2. I need to return some custom user data if the user is authenticated. Is it better to
   call GetUser and check for null or just call ValidateUser and then
   grab a user object?

   1. Where and how should I store the custom data for the user? Is it stored in the identity object? Should I store it in the MembershipUser Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you verify that the credentials are correct by doing a call such as

```
Membership.ValidateUser(TextBoxUsername.Text, TextBoxPassword.Text)
```

If the above call returns `true` then you need to set the authentication cookie like so:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(TextBoxUsername.Text, CheckboxRememberMe.Checked);
```

There I used a "remember me" checkbox if you want to login automatically next time.

To get the user details you can call

```
Membership.FindUsersByName(TextBoxUsername.Text)
```

The most handy place you can store the user details is the session.

You didn't ask, but just as important would be a log out page. The functionality needed to undo the login steps are:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();
Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", false);//or homepage, or any other page
```